# Anguarjs - `orderBy` not works as expected in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have no.of `input` field to edit by user. when user edits the value I am trying to `re-wrap` the array. when i do I would like to sort the values in controller. for that i do :

```
gridView.resort = function( ){
        var start = new Date( );
        gridView.gridData = $filter( 'orderBy')(slice, "mk", true );
    }
```

when I console the filter I am getting like this:

```
119
gridData.js:22 879
gridData.js:22 470
gridData.js:22 420
gridData.js:22 392
gridData.js:22 347
gridData.js:22 293
gridData.js:22 234
gridData.js:22 170
gridData.js:22 120
```

But this is not work for me. when I change the value in one of the field with lesser number it sit on the first row, and it not sorted entire rows. any help?

on page load sortBy works for me :

```
apiService.generateData( ).then(function( data ){

        var start = new Date( );

        gridView.gridData =  slice = $filter( 'orderBy')(data.splice( 0, 10 ), "mk");


    });
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwqcEb8vxTjYgEkHFsQH?p=preview)
(Enter some low values and see the out put )

Comment: Define "does not work". What is the input, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output? We have no idea of what slice, "mk", gridData, etc. are. We also don't know what the template displays. gridData or slice?

Comment: I agree. I finding the problem here. when page loads all values are being as numbers, so I am getting proper sort. when user modified the model, that because `string`, so not come under proper sort. How to handle this scenario. let me try to update `live` demo

Comment: Here is the demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/WwqcEb8vxTjYgEkHFsQH?p=preview please enter some low values, it not re-appending the hole list

Comment: Fixed it for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/OeUvhI7rvAZf1JCTdoy7?p=preview. If your goal is to store numbers in your model, use inputs of type number, not text.

Comment: But we can't expect alwasy we can use the `type:number` - right. because number gives scroll or browser compatibility issues. how can we handle with using the `text` type itself

Comment: Angular deals with the number type for you, even if it's not natively supported by the browser. If you absolutely want to use the text type, then I would start by making all the ages strings and not number (to avoid having to deal with mixed data types), and parse the strings to numbers before comparing. But again, use number inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @JB Nizet, you should consider using `number` instead of `text`.

there is still one way to deal with `text` which is invoking `parseInt` at `ng-change` event, but rememer that this will throw error when some thing else of number when you are typing(means you have to controll what can be typing in).

see the working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3j8eUJqGqYgYfy7eapm3?p=preview).